# How to get single value of array from mysql table and used in search

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table `bp` in my MySQL database in which there are two columns `category_cod` and `material_cod`. Both columns have stored multiple value in single row like `category_cod` have `2,4,5` and `material_cod` have `7,12`. I am trying to get all the `category_cod` against the value of each `material_cod` like I want to get `category_cod` where `material_cod` is `7` and then get results against each `category_cod`

Here is my table structure:

[image]

So far my my query is:

```
 select category_cod from bp where material_cod like '%7%'
```

Comment: You should normalize your database and stop using comma separated values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use [FIND_IN_SET](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_find_in_set.asp) in mysql

**Dis :-** The FIND_IN_SET() function returns the position of a string in a comma-separated string list.

```
SELECT category_cod FROM bp WHERE FIND_IN_SET(7, material_cod)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use limit:

```
select category_cod from bp where material_cod like '%7%' limit 1
```